# PowerShell How to convert Get-ChildItem output to a string array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

Alright, been working on this for hours and researching like crazy, but still not getting something to work. I need a `string[]` object created from `get-childitem` to pass to the `Copy-Item` `-exclude` parameter.

The hurdle is that I need to do recursion and need to have relative paths, so this is what I came up with:

```
$((Get-ChildItem -Path $Dest -Recurse -File).FullName.TrimStart($Dest))
```

This results in a clean list of existing files in `$dest` that are presented with a relative path to `$dest`. The problem is, if I add this to the `copy-item` `-exclude` parameter it seems to ignore it. Further research online suggests that `copy-item` will ignore the `-exclude` parameter if it is not of type `string[]`.

If I check the type returned by the above command, I get `System.Object[]`. I expect it to be `System.String[]` or just plain `String[]`.

**How do I convert the output of the above command to a string array?**

The full command using `copy-item`, for clarity, is:

```
Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path $src "*") -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force -Exclude $((Get-ChildItem -Path $Dest -Recurse -File).FullName.TrimStart($Dest))
```

My end goal is to copy files recursively without overwriting existing files.

Comment: `-Exclude` (and `-Include`) only support file _name_ patterns, not _paths_. However, adding support for paths is being discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4126).

Comment: Just so you know, that's not how [`TrimStart()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart) is supposed to be used.  It takes an array of characters for which all occurrences will be removed from the beginning of the string, not an exact string to be removed from the beginning; for that you'd want something like `.FullName.Substring($Dest.Length)`.  Apparently `TrimStart($Dest)` works for you here, which suggests `$Dest` does _not_ contain a trailing backslash.  With a trailing backslash it might remove characters from the relative child path beyond the length of `$Dest`.

Comment: Trimstart() doesn't do what you think it does.  For example, this will result in an empty string:  `'ababab'.trimstart('ab')`.

Answer (score 9):

To get a string[] from the names of get-childitem cmdlet use the following

```
[string[]]$files = (Get-ChildItem).Name
```

Comment: This should be Flagged as the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what it appears you say that you want? But, I think that may not be everything to your question.

```
$((Get-ChildItem -Path $Dest -Recurse -File).FullName.Replace("$Dest",'.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

@mklement0 is right, `-Exclude` and `-Include` support file name patterns (i.e. "*.txt") and not an array of explicit paths.

This sounds like an awful lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/226783) ;-)

If you simply want to copy files recursively without overwriting them, use [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) with the *Mirror* switch. e.g.:

```
robocopy C:/Source C:/Dest /mir
```

---

EDIT:

By default `Copy-Item` will always overwrite the files on copy, and there is no switches to get around this. I usually recommend Robocopy as it ***really*** simplifies things like this and is very "robust" and reliable.

If your requirements are for a "pure" PowerShell version, then you have to break the scrip out into two parts, 1. Get a list of all the files 2. Iterate through the filer and test to see if they are already in the destination before copying.

```
$SrcPath = "C:/Source"
$DestPath = "C:/Dest"

$SrcFiles = Get-ChildItem $SrcPath -Recurse

#Iterate through files testing:
$SrcFiles | ForEach-Object {
    #Calculate Destination File/Folder name/path
    $DestObj = $_.FullName.Replace($SrcPath, $DestPath)

    if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $DestObj)
    {
        #File already Exists
        Write-Host "File already Exists: $DestObj"
    }
    else
    {
        #File Does not exist - Copy
        Write-Host "File Does not Exist Copy: $DestObj"
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $DestObj
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I’m aware of RoboCopy and also aware that it is often a proposed solution. However, I expect powershell to be able to easily copy files without overwriting existing files. I do not want to fire up a third party executable and then try to account for errorhandling and logging in that executable to do an extremely simple task.

Comment: Yeah, by default `Copy-Item` always overwrites. Please see edits above where I have provided a full native PowerShell solution.

Comment: @Appleoddity, `Robocopy.exe` is not a third-party executable. It is part of the Windows operating system.